# Overdetermination of the Maxwell-Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

I‘ve heard people talk about the overdetermination of the Maxwell equations, which are of course:

$$
\nabla \cdot E =\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}\\
$$
$$
 \nabla \cdot B=0 \\
$$
$$
 \nabla \times E=-\partial_t B \\
$$
$$
 \nabla \times B = \mu_0 J + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \partial_t E
$$

I assume by overdetermined they mean that by applying the divergence operator to the last two and using $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times F)=0$ (for twice differentiable vector fields F) it follows that:

$$
-\partial_t \nabla \cdot B = 0
$$
and
$$
\mu_0 \nabla \cdot J + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \partial_t \nabla \cdot E =0
$$
Now using the **continuity equation** $\nabla \cdot J = -\partial_t \rho$:
$$
0=-\mu_0 \partial_t \rho+\mu_0 \epsilon_0 \partial_t \nabla \cdot E =\mu_0 \partial_t(\epsilon_0 \nabla \cdot E- \rho)
$$

This implies that $\nabla \cdot B$ and $\epsilon_0 \nabla \cdot E-\rho$ are time independent, so if the initial conditions fulfill $\nabla \cdot B=0$ and $\nabla \cdot E=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ then these identities hold for all times, therefore the first two Maxwell equations are redundant.

I don’t understand why we were allowed to use the continuity equation $\nabla \cdot J=-\partial_t \rho$ here, doesn’t this add more information on how B and E are linked? Have I therefore cheated in my derivation above?

Comment: This [PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/557013/missing-equations-in-maxwells-equations) is closely related. The continuity equation says nothing else than electric charges are conserved. Seems plausible and can be taken as a law of nature. Quantum field theory has ways to prove it using Noether's theorem.

Comment: But what if I ignore the real world and just consider them as a mathematical system of PDEs for the vector fields. Do I then need the continuity equation to determine the solution to an IVP? (Because the continuity equation no longer follows from my system of differential equations if I exclude Gausses law as suggested)

Comment: That's probably true. Please explore this a bit. I have never done it.

Comment: the four eqs are independent of each other.
see the post:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/702278/is-this-transfer-correct